# Matlab: making an array of numbers divisible by 3

Tags: matlab

I want to generate an array of random numbers that are divisible by 3 in matlab. What is the way to do this?

Comment: Use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate the array and then multiply that by `3`?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
a = randi(100, 5) * 3;
a = a(:);
```

use `randi(100, 5)` to create a pseudo random `5x5` matrix of integers between `1` and `100`. multiply by `3` to make them all divisible by `3`. use the colon operator `:` to convert it to a `25` long array.

As suggested by @tashuhka you can avoid the `:` by:

```
a = randi(100, [25,1]) * 3;
```

You can read all about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)

Comment: `a = randi(100, [25,1]) * 3;` should give the same result.